# Devise change password format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Is there any way to change the default password validation with devise?

I am currently using the rails 3.2 and devise 2.1 and using validation on user model as,

```
 validates :password, :format => { :with => /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,}$/,
 :message => "Password should contain at least 8 characters, one upper case, one lower case and one numeric." }
```

But this is leading to trouble as password only exist while creating the user or updating the password.

Can anybody help me with this.

Comment: It sounds like you want to disable hashing of the passwords, not changing the `with` format.

Comment: Thanks Emil for your time, but I didn't got **disable hashing of the passwords**. I am not using **with** because I am not using validate_format_of.

Comment: Password are usually hashed, which means they are encrypted with a *one-way* encryption algorithm. This is to prevent large-scale problems with a leaked password database. I will not help you disable password hashing, though, for two reasons: 1) Passwords should always be stored hashed, in my opinion, and 2) I don't know how to do it with your specific system.

Comment: That's very true and I also don't want to bother about hashing. I just want to ensure that user entered password need to be in given format.

Comment: Maybe you'll find what you want in devise "How To's" : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages   ; The one called "How To: Allow users to edit their account without providing a password" may be what you're looking for

Comment: It's not actually about editing user's account without password, but ensuring that user enters the password with given complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check deivse security extension gem, he had the exact feature you need.  https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension